Are "help me develop this strategy" questions in scope?
We had our first question yesterday along the lines of "help me to develop a better strategy":

"Mean reverting strategies"

I'm inclined to define non-specific strategy development questions as off-topic since they can drag the quality of questions down.  Questions should ideally be related to a specific model, application, or tool, something tangible.
Should this question be in-scope?  Are there things that we can put in the FAQ to confine these kinds of questions?

I voted to close that question. I think it's vague, for starters, and makes this forum look like EliteTrader or something.
Questions may involve model ideas, but they should be specific to a particular need.
Good:

Why do RSI reversion strategies use a moving average rather than a moving median?

Bad:

What are some reversion strategies you've had success with?


+1 I like your distinction.

agree. voted to close
